# Why is my React Tic-Tac-Toe game score for the player updating by two rather than one but the AI score works fine

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm making a React tic tac toe game against an AI where the score for both the player and AI are displayed and updated as the game is played using useState().  However, I have an issue where when the player wins the player score increases by two rather than one but the AI score increases by one just fine.  I'm still getting the hang of React but it looks like something is causing my code to re-render twice when the player wins.  I thought it might be the React.StrictMode in my index.js file but that didn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my code for the gameplay.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Board from "./board";
import Square from "./square";

const empty_squares = () => (new Array(9)).fill(null);

const GamePlay = () => {
const [squares, setSquares] = useState(empty_squares());
const [playerWins, setPlayerWins] = useState(0);
const [compWins, setCompWins] = useState(0);

const lines = [
    [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8],
    [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8], [2,4,6]
]

 const params = useParams()

 useEffect(() => {
    const comp_turn = squares.filter(square => square !== null).length % 2 === 1;
    function linesMatch(x,y,z) {
        return lines.filter(square_indexes => {
            const square_shapes = square_indexes.map(index => squares[index]);
            return JSON.stringify([x,y,z].sort()) === JSON.stringify(square_shapes.sort());
        });
    };
    const playerWon = linesMatch('X','X','X').length > 0;
    const compWon = linesMatch('O','O','O').length > 0;
    if (playerWon) {   
        setPlayerWins(playerWins + 1);           
        console.log('Player score: ',playerWins)
        setSquares(empty_squares);
    }
    if (compWon) {
        setCompWins(compWins + 1);
        setSquares(empty_squares);
    }
    function comp_choose(index) {
        let comp_square = squares;
        comp_square[index] = 'O';
        setSquares([...comp_square]);
    };
    if (comp_turn) {
        const empty_squares = squares
            .map((square, index) => square === null ? index : null)
            .filter(val => val !== null);

        const random_square = empty_squares[Math.ceil(Math.random() * empty_squares.length)];
        comp_choose(random_square);

    }
 }, [squares]);

 function clickSquare(index) {
    const player_turn = squares.filter(square => square !== null).length % 2 === 0;
    if (player_turn) {
        let player_square = squares;
        player_square[index] = 'X';
        setSquares([...player_square]);
    }
 }
 
return (
    <main>
        <h2 className="pushtoleft">We're playing up to {params.games} games</h2>
        <Board>
            {squares.map((square, index) => 
                <Square
                    x={square==='X'?1:0}
                    o={square==='O'?1:0} 
                    onClick={() => clickSquare(index)} 
                />
            )}
        </Board>
        <h3>Player Score: {playerWins}</h3>
        <h3>Computer Score: {compWins}</h3>
    </main>
 );
}

export default GamePlay;
```

Comment: Have you try `setPlayerWins(prev=>prev + 1);`?

Comment: @Shuo I tried it but it doesn't work sadly